# Creating a GUI like interface using HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a resizable HTML page that mimics the Java applet clock layout and I am not sure if I am approaching this in the right way.

This three clock picture below is what I am trying to create now. Currently I used `div`, `margins` and `padding` to lay out the clock using CSS but since the font-size are all different per line I am using the vmin font to handle the auto-resizing, but with mixed results.  I have being looking online for a tutorial or examples that would address how to do this without success since the examples are resizing text paragraphs that are the same font-size throughout, or are using images.

Does anyone know of a tutorial site or example that addresses this type of problem?  Maybe I should be doing this using `canvas` or something instead of `div` tags.

[image: three clocks]

This was my 1 clock page minus all the CSS stuff:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="AOS/LOS Clock" />
    <title>AOS/LOS Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mc_style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/mc_clocks.js?color=00ff00&file=input/aos_times_json;\"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mc_engine.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="clockAOS" class="clock missionColor"></div>
      <div class="title missionColor"><span>Acquisition of Signal</span></div>
      <div id="relay" class="siteTdrs"></div>
      <div id="clockLOS" class="clock missionColor"></div>
      <div class="title missionColor"><span>Loss of Signal</span></div>
    </div>
    <p id="Msgs"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for laying out elements on a page. You can create a simple layout easily and it will be responsive.

As far as font size goes, there is no way to show the page the same across all browsers and devices. Even using pixels which is a fairly common standard will have different results on retina displays. [Read this](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-font-sizing-tutorial/) to learn more about font sizing.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the vs font descriptions and redid my css sheet.  This resizes the fonts but the negative margin-left doesn't look the same on the linux box vs. PC even though I am using the same terminal screen.  Its better then before however.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

body {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    margin: 2vw 10vw 2vw 10vw;
}

span {
    white-space: nowrap;    /* Specify that the text in element will never wrap */
}

.header {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-weight: bold;  /* bold font */
    color: lightGray;   // color for tdrs/site
}
.header-split      { 
    display:block;
    margin-left:15vw;
}
.header-split span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
#header-ul {
    border-bottom: 3px solid lightgrey
}

#rm {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:-10vw;
}
.siteTdrs {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;  /* bold font */
    color: lightGray;   // color for tdrs/site
}
.mission {
    font-size: 4vw;
}

.clock {
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
}

.terraColor {
    color: #00ff00; // GREEN
}
.aquaColor {
    color: #00ffff; // CYAN
}
.auraColor {
    color: #ffc800; // ORANGE
}

</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header-ul"><div class="header header-split">AOS<span>LOS</span></div></div>

      <div id="rm" ><span id="terraRelay" class="siteTdrs">TDE</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="mission terraColor">TERRA</span></div>
      <div id="terraTime" class="clock terraColor"><span>00:00:00&nbsp;&nbsp;00:00:00</span></div>

      <div id="rm" ><span id="aquaaRelay" class="siteTdrs">SG1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="mission aquaColor">AQUA</span></div>
      <div id="aquaTime" class="clock aquaColor"><span>00:00:00&nbsp;&nbsp;00:00:00</span></div>

      <div id="rm" ><span id="auraRelay" class="siteTdrs">TDW</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="mission auraColor">AURA</span></div>
      <div id="auraTime" class="clock auraColor"><span>00:00:00&nbsp;&nbsp;00:00:00</span></div>
    </div>
    <p id="Msgs">this is a error</p>
</body>

</html>
```